# Salesforce CRM and Marketing Cloud - Data Extensions

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a client who has a bunch of data in their Salesforce CRM.

We (my company) are passing data specifically to their Marketing cloud data extension, and NOT to their crm.

I have reason to believe that these leads are coming from the extension table because many of the leads contain fields that we are passing to Marketing cloud.  The client is saying that it is not case.  I don't believe him.

The question is: For customer data passed into their Marketing cloud data extension, is an entry automatically created for the customer in the CRM?  Is there some type of setting that is in control of this? In what way would that data be getting in there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Marketing Cloud Connect** data that you are seeing in you Marketing Cloud instance are in read-only mode, as synchronisation is not working in both directions in the same way.

You can easily bring all **Salesforce** objects into **Marketing Cloud** as Synchronised Data Extensions, but they are in read-only mode. You can't modify them from Marketing Cloud level. As we can read in [Marketing Cloud documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/integrated_products__crm_and_web_analytic_solutions/marketing_cloud_connector_v5/features/synchronized_data_sources/):

> Synchronized Data Sources allows you to access data from the Sales and Service Clouds within the Marketing Cloud for use in your marketing activities. As changes occur in the Sales or Service Clouds, the Marketing Cloud receives those updates.

Back to the **SalesForce** you can push tracking and analytics, both as individual stats as well as aggregated reports.